# Is the recommendation to have different files on separate disks valid for SQL server in a SAN (RAID) network?

Tags: sql-server, san, raid

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver15#Recommendations

> To maximize performance, create files or filegroups on different
> available disks as possible. Put objects that compete heavily for
> space in different filegroups.

> Use filegroups to enable placement of objects on specific physical
> disks.

> Put different tables used in the same join queries in different
> filegroups. This step will improve performance, because of parallel
> disk I/O searching for joined data.

> Put heavily accessed tables and the nonclustered indexes that belong
> to those tables on different filegroups. Using different filegroups
> will improve performance, because of parallel I/O if the files are
> located on different physical disks.

> Don't put the transaction log file(s) on the same physical disk that
> has the other files and filegroups.

In a SAN network, is there any benefit to creating files or filegroups on different disks? or any of the above quotes?

I am asking because the SAN network has multiple disks and a single file is scattered amongst multiple disks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server - Separating data, log, and TempDB files on a SAN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35404/sql-server-separating-data-log-and-tempdb-files-on-a-san)

Comment: I will start by asking how is your SAN configured, Data files on RAID 10, RAID 1 for log files and Tempdb on RAID 5. But again these things change for how intensive your workload is, how your tempdb is used. Lots of factor here. Multiple disks carved out of SAN as I said above will always help.